# How to set output of VLC media player to decklink-Ultrastudio-SDI output? (VLC-Command-line)

Tags: command-line, video, graphics-card, vlc-media-player

I need to play a video file and send video to decklink output as PAL, But I didn't see anything about Decklink-Blackmagic in the vlc-help.txt.

How can I send a video to decklink-Ultrastudio-SDI output?

OS = Windows 7

Comment: Depending on how the software of this device works, you may be able to accomplish playing a video to it using OBS, or "[Open Broadcaster Software](https://obsproject.com/)" in combination with the [video source plugin](https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/video-source-plugin.20/). This would essentially create a virtual web cam playing your video. Then all you need is software that can take that "webcam" and send the video to your Ultrastudio.